# Raspberry Pi をWi-Fi の AP として利用する際の電波強度は 10mW を上限とするべき？

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

私はRaspberry Pi 4でAPを建てているのですが、電波法で「免許を必要としない無線局」の出力上限が1000mWだと知りました。

しかし、以下のサイトの記述によれば10mWが上限なのかなと思っているのですが、
Raspberry Pi 4のAPはルーターの上限に合わせないといけないのかを知りたいです.
よろしくお願いします.

[Vol.8 無線LANの電波の届く範囲・距離について - エレコム](https://www2.elecom.co.jp/network/wireless-lan/column/wifi_column/vol08/)

> 無線LANルーターやトランシーバーなど「免許を必要としない無線局」の出力上限を定めています。2010年に改正電波法が公布され、この出力上限は従来の10mWから1000mWへと引き上げられました。しかしこの上限は現状では無線LANルーターに適応されておらず、どんなに「ハイパワー」を謳っている無線LANルーターも、日本国内で正規に販売されているものであれば10mWの上限を越えていないはずです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

法律が絡んでくるので、真面目に守るつもりなら総務省への問い合わせも検討してください。

リンク先を読んだ素人の感想として、電波法の改正で上限が引き上げられたにも関わらず多くの製品が 10mW なのは「まったく障害物のない状況であれば、直線距離100ｍくらいなら通信が可能。最大250ｍでの通信に成功」なのと、日本の住宅事情を踏まえて…なのではないでしょうか？
電波の出力と飛距離がきれいに比例するのかわかりませんが、あなたの作るAPで 10mW 以上の出力が必要なのかを検討してください。

また、以下のページで RasPi 4 Model B の技適証明が確認できます。この範囲で使う分には問題ないのではないでしょうか。

[Raspberry Pi 4 Model Bの技適証明](https://www.tele.soumu.go.jp/giteki/SearchServlet?pageID=jg01_01&PC=007&TC=N&PK=1&FN=190925N007&SN=%94F%8F%D8&LN=20&R1=*****&R2=*****)

> **電波の型式、周波数及び空中線電力**
>
> Ｆ１Ｄ　2402～2480ＭＨz(1000kＨz間隔79波)　0.000042Ｗ／ＭＨz
> Ｇ１Ｄ　2402～2480ＭＨz(1000kＨz間隔79波)　0.000018Ｗ／ＭＨz
> Ｆ１Ｄ　2402～2480ＭＨz(2000kＨz間隔40波)　0.002022Ｗ／ＭＨz
> Ｇ１Ｄ　2412～2472ＭＨz( ５ＭＨz間隔13波)　0.002942Ｗ／ＭＨz
> Ｇ１Ｄ，Ｄ１Ｄ　2412～2472ＭＨz(５ＭＨz間隔13波)　0.001842Ｗ／ＭＨz，0.001573Ｗ／ＭＨz
> Ｇ１Ｄ，Ｄ１Ｄ　2422～2462ＭＨz(５ＭＨz間隔９波)　0.001013Ｗ／ＭＨz